# Скрипт не работает по cron

Tags: bash

Есть следующий скрипт бекапа mysql:

```
#!/bin/bash

ST_AUTH="<redacted>"
ST_USER="<redacted>"
ST_KEY="<redacted>"
DUMP_DIRECTORY=/tmp/database-dumps
CONTAINER_NAME=<redacted>
OBJECT_PREFIX="$(hostname)-v2/"
ARCHIVE_NAME=/tmp/databases.tar.gz
QUARTER=$(((($(date +%m) - 1) / 3) + 1))
DAILY_OBJECT_NAME="$OBJECT_PREFIX""databases-daily.tar.gz"
WEEKLY_OBJECT_NAME="$OBJECT_PREFIX""databases-weekly.tar.gz"
QUARTER_OBJECT_NAME="$OBJECT_PREFIX""databases-quarter-$QUARTER.tar.gz"
DAY_OF_WEEK=$(date +%u)

mkdir -p "$DUMP_DIRECTORY"
cd "$DUMP_DIRECTORY"

for DATABASE in $(echo 'show databases' | mysql); do
  if [ "mysql" == "$DATABASE" ] || [ "performance_schema" == "$DATABASE" ] || [ "information_schema" == "$DATABASE" ] || [ "Database" == "$DATABASE" ]; then
    echo "Skipping database $DATABASE"
    continue
  fi

  echo "Saving database $DATABASE"
  mysqldump "$DATABASE" > "$DUMP_DIRECTORY/$DATABASE.sql"
done

echo "Archiving database dumps"
tar -czvf "$ARCHIVE_NAME" .
echo "Uploading $DAILY_OBJECT_NAME"
swift upload -A "$ST_AUTH" -U "$ST_USER" -K "$ST_KEY" --object-name="$DAILY_OBJECT_NAME" "$CONTAINER_NAME" "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
if [ "$DAY_OF_WEEK" -eq "7" ]; then
  echo "Uploading $WEEKLY_OBJECT_NAME"
  swift upload -A "$ST_AUTH" -U "$ST_USER" -K "$ST_KEY" --object-name="$WEEKLY_OBJECT_NAME" "$CONTAINER_NAME" "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
else
  echo "Not uploading weekly backup, current day: $DAY_OF_WEEK, expected: 7"
fi
echo "Uploading $QUARTER_OBJECT_NAME"
swift upload -A "$ST_AUTH" -U "$ST_USER" -K "$ST_KEY" --object-name="$QUARTER_OBJECT_NAME" "$CONTAINER_NAME" "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
echo "Cleaning up"
rm "$ARCHIVE_NAME"
#rm "$DUMP_DIRECTORY/"*.sql
#rmdir "$DUMP_DIRECTORY"
```

Проблема в следующем: скрипт отрабатывает на ура по ручному выполнению, по крону выводит в лог-файл ровно такой же вывод, но в swift-хранилище бэкапы не появляются. Есть идеи, почему это может происходить?

Прошу прощения за непредоставление минимально работающего варианта, сейчас не могу это сделать из-за нехватки времени.

Comment: [это](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/81183/) пробовали?

Comment: добавьте разговорчивости программе *swift* (опция `-v`) и выводите в лог и статус завершения каждого вызова этой программы (`echo $?`).

Comment: @BOPOH данные подключения передаются с помощью аргументов -A -U -K, задаются прямо в скрипте; в env при ручном выполнении их точно нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка нашлась, конечно же, в $PATH - swift лежал по адресу /usr/local/bin/swift, а я логировал тупым перенаправлением в файл (`> /var/log/last-database-backup-run.log`), забыв перенаправить также и stderr (`2>&1`). Поэтому создавалось впечатление, что со скриптом все в порядке, в то время как в stderr сыпались сообщения о том, что бинарник не найден. К сожалению, последние две строки были закомментированы уже только после инцидента, поэтому вы можете догадаться, какого масштаба была драма.

Спасибо @BOPOH и @alexanderbarakin за участие.

Comment: вот думал же про ошибки, да подумал слишком очевидно было бы ))